# Excel Help: Applying Conditional Formatting to Numbers in Percentage format

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I am currently trying to apply conditional formatting to certain rows which contain numbers in percentage (e.g. F11 to N11; F14 to N14; F17 to N17 and so on). These are also the only rows in the worksheet that have numbers in percentage. Would like to know what the fastest way to go about doing this is.

Should I:

(i) apply conditional formatting to the whole worksheet to numbers in percentage (if possible) or

(ii) apply conditional formatting to each individual row which is extremely time-consuming?

Appreciate if anyone can help.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: http://pakaccountants.com/excel-conditional-formatting-highlight-percentage-range/

Answer (score 0):

If your data in the percentage rows is also formatted as percentage, you can use the `=CELL("format",[reference])` function, that returns `"P0"` or `"P2"` for percentage formatting.

Use a helper column (which you can hide if you want) to check the formatting of the first/last cell in the row, and then set conditional formatting based on the column:

[image: A helper column]

After you create the column, you set a conditional formatting rule on the the upper-left cell in the range based on the formula: `=[top cell in helper column]="P0"`. Keep the column fixed with a `$` but not the row, as in the screenshot below, so you can drag the formatting to all the range with correct reference to the helper column.

[image: formatting based on a column]

Next step is to drag this cell to all the range, choosing the "formatting only" option:

[image: Drag formatting]

Finally, you have to format again all rows that contains percentage values to percentage formatting.

However, if the place of the percentage rows is fixed, you don't need that `CELL()` function, just write in the helper column something like `p` or `1` for the rows to format.

(I have also tried to plug the formula directly to the formatting condition, but it doesn't work well all the time)

Tell me if it solved your problem ;)

Comment: @Spherical Please consider [marking this as the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your problem, so it will help others ;)